# How to trigger JavaScript/jQuery on AJAX-enabled ImageField submit?

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript, entities

I'm trying to trigger a JavaScript event when an AJAX-enabled ImageField submit button is clicked.

I've tried variations on `delegate()`, `submit()`, and `click()`, but no joy.

This is something similar to what I'm trying:

```
$('#edit-field-image-und-0-upload-button').mousedown(function () {
  alert('hi');
});
```

I read the documentation I could find on Drupal's AJAX forms, but haven't found what I'm looking for yet.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with DeeZone that [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) should work.

Try putting that code in a `$(document).ready();`

Drupal ajaxifies it's stuff on document ready so your code might be executing BEFORE the form gets ajaxified by Drupal.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#edit-field-image-und-0-upload-button').click(function () {
  alert('hi');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd check your selector #edit-field-image-und-0-upload-button to make sure it's valid, "und" seems kind of odd but I'm not sure. The event handler [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) should do the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'valid'. The characters 'und' are valid in jQuery, and a `click()` handler on the div selector `#edit-field-image-und-0-upload` on the same page works just fine. As stated in the question, `click()` does not work on this selector.

Comment: "Valid" as in is it really a selector that's working and can be referenced. Perhaps "und" in the ID name is fine, just seems odd to me considering all the other terms in the name are human readable such as "edit" and "field", etc. I just was wondering if it was a typo. If you in fact have two different elements on the page with the same ID then that too can be an issue as an ID must be unique but perhaps you were just testing on different elements. Sorry, that's all I have to offer without seeing the code for the whole page.

Comment: und is the language indicator and is perfectly fine.